# Diffraction grating problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, diffraction

We have 8 slits, each separated from its neighbour by $ 0.05$mm. We use light of wavelength $576$nm. The problem is to calculate at what angle the first minimum occurs. The answer is given: $1.44\times{10}^{-3}$ rad. I used $$ \sin\theta = \frac{\lambda}{2d} $$ For destructive interference. And inserting the values as above I get $5.76\times10^{-3} $rad which is out by a factor of 4. I suspect the crux of the problem lies in the wording of the slit separation value. Help is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the spacing for just two slits. If you consider slits that are 4 apart, they can produce interference too. Interference of slits 1&5, 2&6, 3&7 and 4&8 can give you a minimum... and it will occur at 1/4 of the angle you computed.